# Symfony 3 - Looking for a Bundle to interacte with a serveur using z39.50 protocol

Tags: symfony, symfony3.x, z39.50

I'm looking for a bundle to interacte with a serveur using z39.50 protocol.

I have found this link on git hub but the latest modified on 2009..

https://github.com/Symfony-Plugins/sfZ3950Plugin/blob/master/README

> $ symfony plugin-install http://plugins.symfony-project.com/sfZ3950Plugin

i would like to try this one but how to replace the symfony plugin-install command ?

Comment: I think that this plugin is for Symfony 1, this installation method don't ring the bell for me

Comment: Do you think it is possible to convert it to symfony 3 ?

Comment: Is not possible, Symfony 1 to 2 have an architecture break, is not possible to achieve this without a complete rewrite

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any PHP library from Symfony, is not necessary that this has been made for Symfony. I was searching and I find [YAZ](http://php.net/manual/en/book.yaz.php), you can use like any native PHP function.

I hope this can help you